# How to organize routes involving multiple collections / resources?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, backend

Supposed that my MongoDB database has 2 collectoins:

```
users
posts
```

For any query just involving one of the collections, they will be handled in the routes

```
api/users/do_stuff
api/posts/do_stuff
```

What is the standard way to organize queries that will involve both collections? Either updating both collections or requiring data from both collections in order to generate a response for the client? What routes should these queries fall under?

Comment: @Evert you commented on the wrong question

Comment: whoops sorry! deleted